# Can I make other's site Android App and publish on playstore? Is there changes of suspended playstore account?

Tags: google-play-services

Can I make other's site Android App and publish on playstore?
Is there chance of suspended playstore account?

Answer (score 0):

If the site is proprietary, you'll probably be faced with copyright infringement as stated in the [Impersonation and Intellectual Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252832/can-i-make-others-site-android-app-and-publish-on-playstore-is-there-changes-o) policy.

> **Impersonation and Intellectual Property** We don’t allow apps or developer accounts that impersonate other entities, brands, or
>   otherwise infringe on intellectual property rights of others
>   (including trademark, copyright, patent, trade secret, and other
>   proprietary rights). We also don’t allow apps that encourage or induce
>   infringement of intellectual property rights.
>
> We will respond to clear notices of alleged copyright infringement.

However if you have the owner's approval, I think you'll be ok.